# Why is $A\cos(2\pi f_ct)$ a non-stationary process?

Tags: homework, random-process, stationary, stochastic

I am studying analog communication and having Communication system - Simon Hykin as one of the reference.

There is a question

> Consider the sinusoidal process$$X(t) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct)$$where the frequency $f_c$ is constant and amplitude $A$ is uniformly distributed:
>   $f(a) = 1 $ for $0\leq a \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Determine weather or not this process is strictly stationary.

Now when I go through the solution it says it is not a stationary process and it is provided in the solution that:

> if $A$ is uniformly distributed then 
>   $${p}_{X_i}(X_1) = \begin{cases}
> \displaystyle\frac{1}{\cos(2\pi f_c t_i)} &\text{for}\quad  0\leq X_1 \leq \cos(2\pi f_c t_i)\\[2ex]0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$

Now:

- How is this provided?
- And why is it concluded that it's non-stationary process?

Comment: you're not saying what $X_i$ is in $${p}_{X_i}(X_1) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{\cos(2\pi f_c t_i)} &\text{for}\quad  0\leq X_1 \leq \cos(2\pi f_c t_i)\\[2ex]0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$ 
is it a p.d.f. for $X(t)$?

Comment: [This answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/32002/4298) to a related question might be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A random process is a *collection of random variables,* one random variable for each time instant. It is best to write the
random process as
$$\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\} \tag{1}$$
where the $\{$ and $\}$ indicate that a *set* (or collection) of
objects is being
defined, and the interior says that a typical member of this set is denoted
by $X(t)$ where $t$ is a real number. Think of $X$ as the family name of all the random variables in the set, and $t$ as the first name. Thus, $X(t_0)$ is just one of the random variables in this collection of random variables, the random variable for time $t_0$, while $X(t_1)$ is another random variable, the one corresponding to time $t_1$.

The statement
$$X(t) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct)$$
is a loose way of writing the more formal definition $\{X(t) = A\cos(2\pi f_c t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$. Thus, we have that
$$X(t_0) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct_0),\\
X(t_1) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct_1),\\
\cdots $$

Since $\cos(2\pi f_ct_0)$, $\cos(2\pi f_ct_1)$ etc are just constants,
what we immediately get is that *each* random variable $X(t_i)$ in
this random process is a *uniformly distributed random variable*. Huh?
How did we get that? Well, $A \sim U(0,1)$ is given, and hopefully
you understand enough about random variables to know (or to be able
to jump
to the conclusion) that $bA \sim U(0,b)$ for $b >0$.  If $b < 0$,
then $bA \sim U(b,0)$.

So, now you have enough information to decipher the *crappy* notation
in the solution given to you (which is not completely correct, anyway). The random variable $X(t_i)$ is given by
$$X(t_i) = A\cos(2\pi f_ct_i) = bA  
\begin{cases} \sim (U(0,b), & b > 0,\\
= 0, & b = 0,\\\sim U(b,0), &b < 0,\end{cases}.$$
Thus, for $b > 0$, we can write the density function of $X(t_i)$ as
$$f_{X(t_i)}(x) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle\frac 1b, & 0 < x < b,\\
0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases}
= \begin{cases} \displaystyle \frac{1}{\cos(2\pi f_ct_i)}, & 0 < x < \cos(2\pi f_ct_i),\\
0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases} \tag 2$$
where of course $t_i$ is such that $\cos(2\pi f_ct_i) = b$.

So, the above derivation of $(2)$ answers your first question. For the
second question re stationarity, the conditions that a random process
must satisfy in order for it to be called a stationary process are
quite onerous (see, for example, the first paragraph of
*[this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235)* to
a different question for details) and this process fails to meet
even the simplest of the *necessary* conditions: that **all** the random
variables comprising the process have the *same* distribution function
(which also means having the *same* density function if the random
variables are continuous random variables). But, it is manifestly
obvious from $(2)$ that $X(t_i)$ and $X(t_j)$ have different
densities in general. That for *certain specific* choices of
$t_i$ and $t_j$, $X(t_i)$ and $X(t_j)$ have the same density (in fact
are the same random variable) is nice to know, but irrelevant. 
**Not all** random variables in the process can be said to
have the same
distribution, and this single inconvenient fact allows us to reject 
any overblown notions that we might be harboring 
that this process is a stationary process.

To avoid follow-on questions from readers, the process in question
is not wide-sense stationary either (hint: because the mean function
is time-varying).

Comment: I should probably have taken the time to straighten out notation. Thanks! Have an upvote.

Comment: Very nicely explained @Dilip.

Comment: Yes, a clear description.  @Dilip.

Comment: *"Well, $A∼U(0,1)$ is given, and hopefully you understand enough about random variables to know (or to be able to jump to the conclusion) that $bA∼U(0,b)$ for $b>0$. If $b<0$, then $bA∼U(b,0)$."* $$ $$ why is that? $$ $$ why isn't it: If $b<0$, then $bA∼U(0,-b)$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson If I understood your concern right, then algebra can provide the answer: given a RV $X$ *uniform* in the range $0<X<1$, then the new random variable $Y = bX$ will be in the range; $0 \cdot b < bX < 1 \cdot b => 0 < bX < b$ hence $U(0,b)$  for $b$ positive number, and $0\cdot b > bX > 1 \cdot b => 0 > bX > b => b<bX <0$ hence $U(b,0)$  for $b$ a negative number; i.e., the *inequality reverses direction* when multiplied by a negative number.

Comment: @Fat32 :  it's the notational convention.  i thought that there was something in common with the $U(\cdot,\cdot)$ notation and the $N(\cdot,\cdot)$ notation, that the arguments meant the same thing, while one was Uniform r.v. and the other a Normal (or Gaussian) r.v.  i thought the arguments for both were standard deviation and mean.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson oh really, that means I have ridiculously missed the point :-) anyway. Yes $U(a,b)$ is used to denote a *uniformly* distributed rv between $a$ and $b$; i.e., $ a < X < b$. (endpoints included or not depending on the type of rv). But unlike special functions of math such as $\cos()$, $\log$, $\delta()$ etc, its usage is not that unique and may require a definition before using it, such as; "Let $U(a,b)$ represents teh PDF of a RV which is uniform over $[a,b]$ "

Answer (score 4):

In easy words:

*A process is stationary if its stochastic properties are independent of the time you look at it.*

Think of it like this: A stochastic process is just a Random Variable (RV) that, instead of giving you e.g. a real value gives you a function every time you look at it. We call that *realizations*.

If you now take a lot of these realizations, and compare them, you'll notice:

- For all $t_0 = \frac{2N+1}{4f_c},\,N\in\mathbb N$, the cosine becomes
  $$\begin{align}
  \cos(2\pi f_c t_0) &= \cos\left(2\pi f_c \frac{2N+1}{4f_c} \right)\\
   &= \cos\left(2\pi \frac{2N+1}{4} \right)\\
   &= \cos\left(\frac12\pi (2N+1) \right)&\text{$\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic}\\
   &= \cos\left(\frac12\pi (1) \right)\\
   &= \cos\left(\frac\pi2 \right)\\
  &=0\text,
  \end{align}$$ and thus, $X(t_0)=0$, absolutely deterministic
- For all $t_1 = \frac{N}{f_c}$, the cosine becomes $\cos(2\pi f_c t ) = \cos(2 pi f_c  \frac{N}{f_c})  = \cos (2 \pi N) = \cos (2\pi) = 1$, and therefore $$X(t_1) = A$$. In other words, whenever you look at that time, the RV is uniformly distributed like $A$.

So, for $t_0$ and $t_1$, $X(t)$ behaves **very** differently. If you want to formalize that, the variance is a good start:

$\text{var}\left(X(t_0)\right)=0$, because, obviously, the value of $0$ doesn't vary, and  $\text{var}\left(X(t_1)\right)= \text{var}\left(A\right)=\frac1{12}(1-0)^2=12^{-1}$ (variance of a bounded uniform distribution).

You can even show that using the *mean*, because the mean of $X(t_0)=0$ is $0$, and the mean of $X(t_1) =A$ is $\frac12$.

You'll very likely get to know *ergodic* processes soon, so

> [What is a good example of an ergodic process?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34976/what-is-a-good-example-of-an-ergodic-process/34982#34982)

might be of interest to you.